# Mysql query per date and per group

Tags: mysql, sql, date, group-by, count

I have an SQL query which counts user uptake (registrations) by day for a particular `group` of users. It also does a cumulative (running total)

```
select Date, Cumulative, Up as Uptake
from (
    select Date, Up, @running_total:=@running_total + Up as Cumulative
    from (
        select distinct(date(`audit`.`created_at`)) as Date, COALESCE(f.uptake, 0) as Up
        from `audit`
        left join ( 
            select date(`users`.`created_at`) as day, count(`users`.`id`) as uptake
            from `users`
            where `users`.`group_uuid` = (select `groups`.`uuid` from `groups` where `groups`.`name` = "companyA")
            group by day 
        ) f on f.day = date(`audit`.`created_at`)
        where `audit`.`created_at` between '2019-07-03' and CURDATE()
    ) c
    JOIN (SELECT @running_total:=0) r
) final
order by Date desc
```

This query is using the `audit` table purely to get me a list of dates reliable even if there are no users created on every day, i know the `audit` table with have a record.

I could get all the groups easily with

```
select `groups`.`name` from `groups`
```

**What i want is...** An entry per day and group with the uptake (and cumulative if possible)
Example:

```
Date         |  Cumulative  |      Uptake     |   group
2020-04-07   |    2         |        1        |   comapnyA  
2020-04-07   |    5         |        3        |   comapnyB  
2020-04-06   |    1         |        0        |   comapnyA  
2020-04-06   |    2         |        1        |   comapnyB  
2020-04-05   |    1         |        1        |   comapnyA  
2020-04-05   |    1         |        1        |   comapnyB  
.... etc
```

Comment: pro tip:  qualify ALL column references with table name or (even better) a short table alias. also, DISTINCT is a keyword, not a function. In the SELECT list it applies to all expressions in the SELECT list, unnecessary parens are allowed but don't change the behavior, so don't add spurious parens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For versions of MySQL before 8.0, we could make use of user-defined variables, as demonstrated in the OP query.

A few notes:

It looks like we started with a simple `GROUP BY created_date, group_uuid` query against just the `users` table to get non-zero counts. But that's got missing rows, where there otherwise be a zero count.

So it looks like we need is a calendar source (a distinct list of dates in a given range, OP query is using query of audit table as calendar source) and we need that cross joined (Cartesian product) to a distinct list of uuid values from group, along with the name. For this exercise, we are going to assume that `uuid` is unique in the `groups` table, and that each `uuid` value is associated with a distinct `name` value. (If that's not true, we'd need to make some adjustments.)

To get the running total separately by group, we'd need to process rows in group order, then within each group, by ascending date order.  As we process rows, we need to reset the running total to zero when we start a new group i.e. when detect a change in the group uuid value.

NOTE: The MySQL Reference Manual gives specific warning about using the user-defined variables, both reading and modifying in the same statement, the order of operations is not guaranteed. Up through MySQL 5.7, with carefully crafted queries, we do observe predictable behavior in the order of operations.

So, we could do something like this:

```
SELECT q.date           AS `Date`
     , q.running_total  AS `Cumulative`
     , q.uptake         AS `Uptake`
     , q.name           AS `Group`
  FROM ( SELECT @rtot := IF(@prev_uuid = grp.uuid,@rtot,0) + IFNULL(cnt.uptake,0) AS `running_total`
              , IFNULL(cnt.uptake,0)                                              AS `uptake` 
              , @prev_uuid := grp.uuid                                           AS `uuid`
              , grp.name                                                         AS `name`
              , cal.date                                                         AS `date`
           FROM ( -- initialize user-defined variables
                  SELECT @prev_uuid := NULL
                       , @rtot := 0
                ) i
          CROSS
           JOIN ( -- calendar source for distinct date values
                  SELECT DATE(a.created_at)  AS `date`
                    FROM `audit` a
                   WHERE a.created_at >= '2019-07-03'
                     AND a.created_at <= DATE(NOW())
                   GROUP BY DATE(a.created_at)
                   ORDER BY DATE(a.created_at)
                ) cal
          CROSS
           JOIN ( -- distinct list of group uuid we want to return
                  SELECT g.uuid       AS `uuid`
                       , MAX(g.name)  AS `name`
                    FROM `groups` g
                   WHERE g.name IN ('CompanyA','CompanyB')
                   GROUP BY g.uuid
                ) grp
           LEFT
           JOIN ( -- count by group and date
                  SELECT u.group_uuid        AS `group_uuid`
                       , DATE(u.created_at)  AS `date`
                       , COUNT(u.id)         AS `uptake`
                    FROM `users` u
                   WHERE u.created_at >= '2019-07-03'
                   GROUP
                      BY u.group_uuid
                       , DATE(u.created_at)
                ) cnt
             ON grp.uuid = cnt.group_uuid
            AND cal.date = cnt.date
          ORDER
             BY grp.uuid
              , cal.date
       ) q
 ORDER
    BY q.date DESC
     , q.name ASC
```

N.B. We have to be careful with the order of operations in the SELECT list that's using the user-defined variables, for example, we need to test the value of @prev_uuid (saved from the previous row) before we overwrite it with the value of the current row.

Also, this is not tested, there could be syntax errors, missing parens. I strongly recommend testing each of the inline view queries separately  (`cal`, `grp`, `cnt`) to verify expected results are being performed. (The WHERE clause in the `grp` query is restricting groups to be returned, adjust or eliminate as required.)

Then we can move on to testing the next outer query `q`, and confirm the results from that, before wrapping `q` in the final outermost query to re-order rows, and display columns in desired order.

** FOLLOWUP **

to see if we can get MySQL to honor the `ORDER BY uuid` , we can modify/replace `q`

Change from this:

```
SELECT q.date           AS `Date`
     , q.running_total  AS `Cumulative`
     , q.uptake         AS `Uptake`
     , q.name           AS `Group`
  FROM ( SELECT @rtot := IF(@prev_uuid = grp.uuid,@rtot,0) + IFNULL(cnt.uptake,0) AS `running_total`
              , IFNULL(cnt.uptake,0)                                              AS `uptake` 
              , @prev_uuid := grp.uuid                                           AS `uuid`
              , grp.name                                                         AS `name`
              , cal.date                                                         AS `date`
           FROM 
                ...
          ORDER
             BY grp.uuid
              , cal.date
       ) q
 ORDER
    BY q.date DESC
     , q.name ASC
```

to

```
SELECT r.date           AS `Date`
     , r.running_total  AS `Cumulative`
     , r.uptake         AS `Uptake`
     , r.name           AS `Group`
  FROM ( SELECT @rtot := IF(@prev_uuid = q.uuid,@rtot,0) + q.uptake AS `running_total`
              , q.uptake                                            AS `uptake`
              , @prev_uuid := q.uuid                                AS `uuid`
              , q.name                                              AS `name`
              , q.date                                              AS `date`
           FROM ( SELECT grp.uuid             AS `uuid`
                       , grp.name             AS `name`
                       , cal.date             AS `date`
                       , IFNULL(cnt.uptake,0) AS `uptake`
                    FROM
                         ...
                   ORDER
                      BY grp.uuid
                       , cal.date
                ) q
          ORDER
             BY q.uuid
              , q.date
       ) r
ORDER
    BY r.date DESC
     , r.name ASC
```

Comment: thanks. on line 5 should that be `IFNULL(cnt.uptake,0)` ?

Comment: also getting unknown column `c.uptake` on line 3

Comment: yes, that third expression in the SELECT list of the outermost query should be `q.running_total`, reference to the running_total col returned from q,  and yes it should be IFNULL(cnt.uptake   reference to the uptake col returned from cnt ... edited

Comment: the inline view queries `cal` and `grp` could be simplified, replaced with reference to bare tables if bare tables return what we need ... i also cleaned up the cnt view query,  removed the join to groups...  we could included that and just return name from groups table, ...  pattern is still the same.  cal cross joined with group, and then outer join to counts , where count rows are missing, we know the counts are zero

Comment: thanks for the update @spencer7593, i have tried that its running ok now. Although i get the uptake (daily registration count) in both Cumulative and Update columns.

Comment: @VinceLowe:  make sure the `@prev_uuid` user defined variable is initialized. also be sure that the rows are sorted by uuid first, then by date. Also be sure the IF function that evalutes the current value of @prev_uuid occurs *before* we assign the current row uuid to @prev_uuid.   reviewing the SQL statement, all three of those things are true...  @prev_uuid is set in inline view `i` (evaluated before outer query executes),  the `@prev_uuid := ` assignment follows the `IF(@prev_uuid = ` comparison,  ...

Comment: @VinceLowe: i would test with just a single value of uuid, see if cumulative is working then. if that works, but not with two values of uuid, then maybe MySQL is evaluating the expressions in the SELECT list *before* the `ORDER BY uuid, date` is honored. we might need to nest in yet another inline view query, to make sure the ORDER BY operation occurs, and then we can do the  @prev_uuid comparison in an outer query. this usage of user defined variables depends on the execution plan having a predictable order of operations

Comment: oh wait, my DERP!  ... the inline view query `q` needs to return `IFNULL(cnt.uptake,0)`  as a separate expression, so it's available in the outermost query,  fixing

Comment: :) cool, now the cumulative works if i set the `WHERE g.name IN` to a single company, if i add a second or remove the `WHERE` completely it goes back to putting the uptake value in cumulative column

Comment: that makes it seem like MySQL is not honoring the `ORDER BY uuid` in the inline view query `q`.  For the user-defined variable trick to work, the rows have to processed in order, all rows for group1, then the rows for group2, then the rows for group3 ... the rows from the groups can't be intermixed. the potential fix is to take inline view `q` , remove all the user-defined variable stuff, and return just the bare grp.uuid, cal.date, cnt.uptake columns.  then make that inline view to another query, to do the user-defined variable processing  `SELECT @rtot = IF(q.  ) , @prev :- q.  FROM () q`

Comment: that follow up got it, impressive work. Thanks for the work, explanations and tips

Comment: Sorry to come back to this, i have noticed that on the first run of the query the cumulative count doesn't work, an immediate rerun it does work.

Comment: @VinceLowe:  That's the behavior we expect if the user-defined variables aren't initialized when the statement runs. That's the purpose of the inline view `i`, to initialize the values. We are relying on MySQL behavior, the derived table `i` is materialized before the outer query runs. We could initialize them with separate SET statements before the SELECT; my preference has been to include the initialization within the query. TODO:  verify the names of the user-defined variables used in the outer statement matches exactly the names in inline view `i`.

Comment: NOTE: Once we get to MySQL 8.0,  we can use the analytic / window functions (i.e.  the  :`... OVER ( PARTITION BY ...)`  syntax that has been long supported by Oracle, SQL Server, et al. ) and abandon user-defined variables, and MySQL behavior that is not guaranteed, usage explicitly warned against in the MySQL Reference Manual.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming MySQL 8.0, I would write this as:

```
select
    a.created_date,
    count(u.created_at) uptake,
    sum(count(*)) over(partition by g.group_uuid order by a.created_at) cumulative
    g.name
from (select distinct date(created_at) created_date from audit) a
cross join groups g 
left join users u 
    on  u.created_at >= a.created_date 
    and u.created_at <  a.created_date + interval 1 day
    and u.group_uuid = g.group_uuid
where a.created_date between '2019-07-03' and current_date
group by a.created_date, g.group_uuid, g.name
order by a.created_date, g.name
```

The query uses a `cross join` to generate all possible combinations of days (from `audit`) and groups (from `groups`). Then we bring the `users` table with a `left join`. We can then aggregate and count how many user records exist for each day/group. A window sum gives the cumulative count.

Comment: thanks @GMB, looks tidy :) i shold have mentioned i am on mysql 5.7.17